# print all duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Now, I have the following query, which gives me the COUNT() of rows which have the same name. However, let's say that I just wanted to have all the rows printed out.

```
SELECT l.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, 
    l.source AS 'affiliateId', COUNT(*), 
    c.email, ls.create_date, ls.buyer 
  FROM lead_status AS ls 
    INNER JOIN leads AS l ON l.id = ls.lead_id 
    INNER JOIN contacts AS c ON c.lead_id = l.id 
  WHERE ls.discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND l.affiliate_id=1003 
    AND ls.winner =1 AND l.test =0 
    AND l.create_date BETWEEN '2011-10-03' AND '2011-10-19'
  GROUP BY c.first_name, c.last_name HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

So I'm trying to go from:

```
joe   smith   3
lisa  martin  2
```

To the following:

```
joe smith   
joe smith
joe smith
lisa martin
lisa martin
```

Help!

Comment: What are the table schema (`CREATE` statements)? Which table/s has/have the duplicates? For example, might a contact appear more than once in the contact table, or might more than one lead refer to the same contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join with a numbers table:

```
SELECT T1.col1, T2.col2
FROM
(
   -- your long query goes here
) T1
JOIN numbers
ON numbers.x <= T1.cnt
```

A numbers table is just a table that contains numbers:

```
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
etc... as many numbers as you will ever need
```

Answer (score 2):

u can use expression `COUNT(DISTINCT first_name)` and then get rid of `GROUP BY`

so query will be

```
SELECT l.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, l.source AS 'affiliateId', COUNT(DISTINCT c.first_name, c.last_name) as CountRows, 
c.email, ls.create_date, ls.buyer FROM lead_status AS ls 
INNER JOIN leads AS l ON l.id = ls.lead_id 
INNER JOIN contacts AS c ON c.lead_id = l.id 
WHERE ls.discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND l.affiliate_id=1003 
AND ls.winner =1 AND l.test =0 AND l.create_date BETWEEN '2011-10-03' AND '2011-10-19'
HAVING CountRows>1
```

Comment: And accomplish what? (serious question)

Comment: He want all rows printed out with COUNT(firstname,lastname) as well? So this is my solution

Comment: You are right - the OP is specifying "same name." But the example provided groups by first and last name, so I think "same name" means "same first and last name," basically meaning "duplicated rows."

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember if MySQL supports subqueries, but I would do something like

```
select
    first, last 
from
    table where id in (select id from table group by first, last having count(*) > 1)
order by
    first, last
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another join on the table(s) where the duplication appears. For the join condition, have the identifying info be the same (e.g. `c.first_name = c2.first_name AND c.last_name = c2.last_name`, or `l.id = c2.id`) and whatever distinguishes the records be different (e.g. `l.create_date < l2.create_date`). Lastly, group by the ID of the record that contains the duplicates or select distinct rows so you don't get repeats. Without knowing the table schema or where the duplicates might occur, I can't be any more specific.

Answer (score 0):

join the result set back with the contacts tale on the first name and last name fields (assuming that first name + last name forms a unique key)